# Inset creating strange, bulky result

Tags: mesh, faces

please excuse my rather vague title, I have no idea how else to describe what I am having here, I hope with the screenshot and maybe further questions from your side there can be a solution found to this.
Now to the matter: I am following a tutorial, here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yxrke72isQ
In this tutorial that guy just used the inset tool to make this roundish edge of that object in question and when he does it it is a smooth line, while when I do it I get separated bulky things which I do not understand, since I was following every step thoroughly.

I hope you guys know this issue and can share your knowledge with me.
Thanks for the attention.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must unckeck **Individual**.

See the image below with the **Individual** checked:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't see, helped a lot! :D